# Is it possible to have object with value only?

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-mongodb-native

I have this piece of code :

```
db.collection('coders', function(err, collection) {
        collection.find(toFind).toArray(function(err, items) {
            res.send(items);
        });
```

where `toFind` is something like `{"position":2,"$or":[{"position":{"$lt":20}},{"name":"whatever"}]}`
It is a String, so the previous code doesn't execute, because it needs an object. I already know, that I can create object from String like

```
var obj={}
obj[key] = {value}
```

But how can I create an object without key ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To convert `toFind` from a string into an object that you can pass into `find`, use [`JSON.parse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse):

```
toFind = JSON.parse(toFind);
```

Answer (score 0):

Everything in JavaScript is an object. However, what you apparently want is a simple variable:

```
obj[key] = value;
```

The object you posted above would be defined exactly like this:

```
var obj = {
    "position": 2,
    "$or": [{
        "position": {
            "$lt": 20
        }
    }, {
        "name": "whatever"
    }]
};
```

Comment: No, you also have primitive types, like boolean, string, number, etc.

Comment: Ah well, that's more of an internal thing though. For example, even a plain `number` has the methods from `Number.prototype`

Comment: [(Not) Everything in JavaScript is an Object](http://blog.brew.com.hk/not-everything-in-javascript-is-an-object/). Numbers are primitives, when you try to access a property from it, JavaScript autoboxes the primitive and accesses that object wrapper's property. See my answer at http://stackoverflow.com/a/44042894/3966682