# Everything is an object?

Tags: javascript

At one popular blog, the author asked his audience what was their “Ah ha!” moment for JavaScript and most of the people said that it was realizing that everything in JavaScript is an object. 
But being new to JS and programming in general I don't quite get what that means. It doesn't seam like it's related to actual JS Object - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object

Or it does?

If it doesn't could you please explain what do they mean by "everything in JavaScript is an object".

Or it's all about OO Programming in general and reading something on this subject will help to understand it? Can you recommend what to read on this topic?

Comment: It's not true that everything in JavaScript is an object.

Comment: in a lot of OOP most everything extends `Object` in some form.

Comment: And further more things that can have object like properties (http://stackoverflow.com/a/6394872/16959) should not imply that you can treat them like objects.

Comment: A function is not an object.

Comment: @caffinatedmonkey functions in JavaScript are indeed objects. Strings and numbers and booleans aren't, however.

Comment: Thanks! @Pointy I'm learning a lot from you.

Comment: Ha ha well that's why I hang out here I guess :) @caffinatedmonkey

Comment: You can mess with the Number type http://jsfiddle.net/3DP7q/ but I think this is beyond what I understand about prototype inheritance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Go back to first principles.

What's an object?  It's a software component that encapsulates state and behavior together into a single entity in memory.

By that definition, you can see where everything can be thought of as an object.  Functional programmers make functions first class objects.  Data folks would say that data, even that without behavior, can be thought of as an object (albeit not a very smart one).

I don't see what this changes.

JavaScript treats functions as objects.

I'm not sure what effect this insight will have on your programming.

Comment: This is all true, but in JavaScript it's simply wrong to say that "everything is an object", because strings, booleans, and numbers are not objects.

Comment: Fair enough.  Java has primitives, too.  What does it change?  I don't know that it matters much.

Comment: Well it matters if you care about "everything" being an object (which I personally don't, of course).

Comment: Agreed.  There are lots of arguments about languages and object-oriented purity.  They leave me cold.  I think it's a subject that's only of academic interest.  I like it when languages are hybrids.  Combining functional and object-oriented features is a good thing, IMO.

Answer (score 8):

What they mean, most likely, is that any data that can be assigned to a variable has properties (and therefore methods) that can be accessed in an object like fashion.

```
// strings
"asdf".length;              // 4
"asdf".replace('f', 'zxc'); // "azxc"

// numbers
(10).toFixed(2);            // "10.00"

// booleans
true.someProp;              // undefined (point is it doesn't crash)
```

They even have prototypes they inherit from.

```
"omg".constructor;          // function String() { [native code] }
String.prototype.snazzify = function() {
  return "*!*!*" + this + "*!*!*";
};

"omg".snazzify();           // "*!*!*omg*!*!*"
```

However, these are primitives, and while they behave object like in a lot of ways, they are different from other "real" JS objects in a few ways.  The biggest of which is that they are immutable.

```
var s = "qwerty";
s.foo;              // undefined, but does not crash
s.foo = 'some val'; // try to add a property to the string
s.foo;              // still undefined, you cannot modify a primitive
```

Do note though that functions are *real* mutable objects.

```
var fn = function(){};
fn.foo;              // undefined
fn.foo = 'some val'; // try to add a property to the function
fn.foo;              // "some val"
```

---

So while it's not technically true that "everything in JS is an object", under most circumstances you can treat them mostly like objects in that they have properties and methods, and can potentially be extended.  Just be sure you understand the caveats.

Comment: Primitives like strings and numbers do *NOT* have any properties or methods. When you run `.length` on the string, JavaScript creates a temporary object wrapper around the primitive and access the `length` property of that object wrapper. This is known as autoboxing.

Answer (score 2):

Not everything is an object in JavaScript. For example a number is not an object.

Different languages have different definition of "object". For JavaScript, the official definitions can be found in the [ECMAScript Language Specification](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/11.0/index.html#sec-ecmascript-overview), which states:

> In ECMAScript, an object is a collection of zero or more properties
> each with attributes that determine how each property can be used (...) Properties are containers that hold other objects,
> primitive values, or functions. A primitive value is a member of one
> of the following built-in types: Undefined, Null, Boolean, Number,
> BigInt, String, and Symbol; an object is a member of the built-in type
> Object; and a function is a callable object.

So by this definition it is clear that primitive values (like numbers) are not objects. Even strings are not objects, which is different from most other OO languages.

So why do some people say "everything is an object"? You have to ask them! But I suspect  it is because they are getting confused by the built-in objects `Number`, `Boolean`, `String` etc. which can be used as wrappers around the corresponding primitive values. This wrapping sometimes happen automatically, which can make primitive values *look* like object and for example allow you to (seemingly) access properties on primitives. But in reality the properties are on the wrapper object.

Answer (score 1):

[***NOT*** everything in JavaScript is an object.](http://blog.brew.com.hk/not-everything-in-javascript-is-an-object/)

All data in JavaScript must fall into one of six primitive types, or the object type. Primitive types includes boolean, `null`, `undefined`, string, number and symbol; **everything that is not a primitive is an object**.

This means functions are objects, arrays are objects, ES6 classes de-sugars into a function which are objects.

The confusion arises because primitive values have *object wrappers*. When you try to access the `length` property on the string literal, JavaScript creates a temporary object wrapper around the primitive and access the length property of that object wrapper. After the property has been retrieved, the object wrapper is discarded. This is known as autoboxing.

Essentially, it is implemented *similar* to the following:

```
const foo = "bar";

// When you run `foo.length`, it's similar to
tmp = String(foo);
tmp.length;
delete tmp;
```

Or

```
const foo = "bar";
(new String(foo)).length;
```

The string, number and boolean primitives have object wrappers, but `null` and `undefined` do not. So trying to access a property or method from those primitives would throw an error.

```
null.length; // Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of null
undefined.length; // Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
```

Answer (score 0):

'**ALMOST** everything is an object' because the MAIN code-units are JS-objects. On primitives you can NOT add members for example as on all objects. My answer why JS-functions are JS-objects here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24811539